# Clearing up some confusion on a Node.js / Express.js / React.js structure

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, server

I'm making a website where you can order stuff online, a shop basically.

But I'm confused on something, `create-react-app` makes its own Node.js server that connects with my backend (where I do MySQL queries and so), but this means that I now have two Node.js servers running on two ports, one for the website (frontend/client) and one for the API (backend).

Is this okay? I thought I'd have them all in one server, where that one server has access to the MySQL backend. I'm really confused here.

Thanks.

Comment: Your frontend development server should listen on a different port number than your backend server. This is completely normal.

Comment: @ozgur I see, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, in development, you have a react development server running so you can see instantaneous updates on your websites which is a separate server from your backend. This is great for development however for production, you would basically deploy the build of your react app.

For more information, you can read the official docs: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/

Comment: Ah, I see, so it's only for the development part. Thanks a lot. I see an example of Express.js in that website, is it also okay to use my backend server (API) to render the website?

Comment: Yes, any backend server would be able to render the build